# AS3 Keyboard Controlled Character - Animation problems with multiple key presses

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, keyboard-events, keyup

I have a keyboard controlled character in a game which has a stationary frame when no
keys are pressed and four different animations for the up, down, left, right directions
(No diagonal movement).

So when left key is pressed, _character moves left across the screen and the left animation is played. When the key is released/Key up the stationary frame plays where the character is still.

This works fine at a slow pace but when multiple keys are being pressed to maneuver around an obstacle etc, the character often sticks to the stationary position and only plays the animations after a delay. The movement of the Movieclip is fine using velocity, but the animations suffer.

Its something to do with the key up handler surely. I’m a beginner so I’m sure I just can’t get my head around some simple logic, but I can’t figure it out! Help me please. No matter how fast I tap the keys I need that animation to play, and only when nothing is being pressed should I see the stationary image.

Character in its own class, with Velocity variables.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject

        [Embed(source="../swfs/characterRes.swf", symbol="Character")]
        public class Character extends MovieClip
        {
            //Public properties
            public var vx:int = 0;
            public var vy:int = 0;

            public function Character()
            {
            }
        }   
}
```

Keydown and KeyUp listeners added.

```
_stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            _stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
```

In enterFrame the characters X and Y position is linked to the velocity

```
private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
        {   
            //Move the game character and check its stage boundaries
            _character.x += _character.vx; 
            _character.y += _character.vy;
        }
```

The keydown handler uses the arrows and WASD to control the velocity and plays that directions specific frame (with embedded animation)

```
private function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == 65 )
            {
                _character.vx = -4;
                _character.gotoAndStop(4);
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT || event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                _character.vx = 4;
                _character.gotoAndStop(5);
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == 87 )
            {
                _character.vy = -4;
                _character.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == 83)
            {
                _character.vy = 4;
                _character.gotoAndStop(3);
            }   
        }
```

Key up handler stops velocity and plays first frame which is the stationary image.

```
private function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT 
                || event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                _character.vx = 0;
                _character.gotoAndStop(1);
            } 
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP 
                || event.keyCode == 87 || event.keyCode == 83 )
            {
                _character.vy = 0;
                _character.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        }
```

I also made the stationary image bright red to make it easier for me to spot and once I start moving the character in different directions I see Red! (literally & figuratively!)

**Update**

Vesper's answer has solved the animation state problem brilliantly but this new control system seems to want to travel diagonally which sends the character on an unwanted path.

My stage is a grid of 50px squares. Character is 50px and 50px boxess (with collision detection) are around with a 50px border around them so the character can maneuver around the stage.

If I press/hold one direction the character moves no problem (left to right and Up to down is fine too.), but if I go left then down or up then right etc, the character will travel that direction then continue that direction around the boxes. When I tested without the boxes the character continues in that direction diagonally.

So if I want to go clockwise around a box (starting in the bottom left side of it), I'll press up, then right and if I dont press down VERY quickly, the character will travel up and right again, towards the top right of the stage. (Character does stop if key is released.)

So if I press two keys from the opposing updown or leftright variables, it wants to travel diagonally. Any ideas how to solve this?

**Final Update**

Vesper's answer solved my original animation problem. I'll ask new questions to deal with remaining queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have four de-facto independent key states, up key pressed/released, down key, left key, right key. Technically one can implement special actions in case of two opposite keys be pressed at one time, in your case it's not needed but it's still worth mentioning. So, you handle all of them separately, and only then choose where should your character face.

```
    var bDown:Boolean=false;
    var bUp:Boolean=false;
    var bLeft:Boolean=false;
    var bRight:Boolean=false;
    // declare vars to store key states. You can use an array if you want

    private function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == 65 )
        {
            bLeft=true;
            // now, instead of directly attaching the movement, just set flag
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT || event.keyCode == 68)
        {
            bRight=true;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == 87 )
        {
            bUp=true;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || event.keyCode == 83)
        {
            bDown=true;
        }   
    }
```

Same for key up handler, setting values to false. Now doing the parsing of the actual character's movement according to keys pressed. The best place is the enter frame handler - good thing you have it in place already.

```
    private function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {   
        var updown:Boolean=Boolean(!(bUp==bDown)); 
        // if both are true or both are false, this is false. If this is true, 
        // we are moving upwards or downwards
        var leftright:Boolean=Boolean(!(bLeft==bRight));
        // same here
        if (!updown && !leftright) {
            // not moving anywhere
            _character.gotoAndStop(1);
            _character.vy=0;
            _character.vx=0; 
            // other mechanics might be in place in case you decide to implement inertia, for example
        } else {
            if (bUp) {
                _character.vy=-4; // hardcoding this might get you issues later
                // will still do for today's task
                _character.gotoAndStop(2);
            } else if (bDown) {
                _character.vy=4;
                _character.gotoAndStop(3);
            } 
            // one side parsed. Note, with this sequence the leftwards or rightwards
            //animation supersedes up/down. But, we don't have diagonals, so there should be superseded animation
            if (bLeft) {
                _character.vx=-4;
                _character.gotoAndStop(4);
            } else if (bRight) {
                _character.vx=4;
                _character.gotoAndStop(5);
            } 
        }
        // Okay, now velocity and facing is set, proceed with move
        //Move the game character and check its stage boundaries
        _character.x += _character.vx; 
        _character.y += _character.vy;
    }
```

Comment: Silly me, I put the updown and leftright variables at the start of the program, not in the enter frame. It works pretty good now, plays appropriate animations and stops when keyup. However the controls are a little out of control the character will choose its own direction around obstacles. Would that be due to the enterframe handler firing off instructions sixty times a second? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is unlikely because of speed, but you can consider lowering the frame rate to 30 for example, as it's most likely your game will eventually be too big to maintain the 60fps. But indeed, you can gather `currentFrame` property from character to not call `gotoAndStop()` if the new frame is the same. The rest of the behavior you describe is unclear to me.

Comment: Hi, sorry for suggesting speed/enterframe being the problem, its nothing to do with that. My problems arnt with the animations anymore but the movement of the actual movieclip object. I added an update in the main question section. I'd be so grateful if you could take a look and help again.

Comment: Hmm. You seem to want to move your character along the grid lines, so if say your char is at lower left corner of the box, you want to press up then right and make it so that the char moves first up to the grid separation, then right to the next grid point. You have to rework the mechanics of movement for this, and really heavily. Velocities approach will no longer work for this, as you'd want your char to either bounce leftwards or downwards vs the box you're about to walk around, and you'd not be able to determine the direction of the bounce. I'd say ask an entirely new question for this.

Comment: The character doesnt have to strictly move along the grid points. Think of the old top down zelda game (up,down,left,right and stable position.) The old controls moved the character object perfectly but the direction animations would get muddled with multiple presses, with your answer the animations work perfectly but the character object moves diagonally when up/left, up/right, down/left or down/right are pressed.

Comment: If I remove all obstacles/boxes from the stage and press any of the variations above the character moves diagonally. If I add the boxes the character maneuvers itself around the boxes due to the collision detection often moving the wrong way. The problem is definitley the want to move diagonally, the old controls wouldnt do this with the boxes, I really dont think its the collision detection. Is there a simple way in your controls to prevent diagonal movement?

Comment: Hmm. You can try using three new positions for the char to check for movement validity, them being (x+vx,y+vy),(x+vx,y) and (x,y+vy). First check diagonal movement, as you want this to exist if no obstacles are present. As soon as a point returns true, move the char there, adjust facing if necessary. If all return false, the char is trying to move into a corner, so put it back to previous position, maybe with "standing" animation.

Comment: Could you get me started on how to implement the three new positions? Sorry, Im a beginner. Are these additions to what I already have or replacements?

Comment: These are additions. You already have a test for the player's new position, so to test three points you just store the values of `x` and `y` of your player MC, then assign them to each of the three points in turn, and once there's no collision, perform a return.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you've completely lost me.  What test do I have for the players position?  _character.x += _character.vx;      _character.y += _character.vy; ???

Comment: If possible I'd really appreciate another code example. If not I'll have to break this up into multiple questions because I'm out of my depth. I cant believe moving a movieclip around a maze would be such a pain!

Comment: The code is as simple as this: `var oldX:Number=_character.x; var oldY:Number=_character.y;` then you assign coordinates for character based on oldX, oldY, vx, vy as needed, test vs obstacles (you have it there somewhere already), if hits, try next point, if doesn't hit, leave coordinates as is and `return`.

Comment: I dont understand the logic, how will this prevent diagonal movement?

Comment: See, if a character hits the obstacle while moving diagonally, it's moved backwards and is then trying to move first horizontally, then vertically while testing against obstacle(s). If any of the moves succeed, the character is moved to the direction that doesn't make it collide with obstacles, that is, either horizontally or vertically, but not diagonally.

Comment: Is the above what the new code will do or what I currently have? Because it sounds like what I currently have, I want to decide where the the character travels at all times. If I have to rework the mechanics fine, but why did that movement work with my original method? But your enterframe method doesnt? I have to rebuild my game as tile based because I want my sprite to have animations that work?! The first methods movieclip movement worked fine around the boxes!

Comment: No data as of now. Perhaps ask another question explaining your issue in detail.

Comment: I will, thanks again. Sorry for dragging it out for a week. Its driving me mad!